# jquery with asp.net dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have numbers of dropdownlist, so i want to change event of every dropdownlist in form, when i select particular dropdownlist item then it will fire event for particular dropdownlist only... 
here is two sample of dropdownlist

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
```

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaritalStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
```

Please help me as soon as possible
Thank you

I tried this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
    $("select").change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        if (this.value != "User Select") {
            alert(this.value);
            $('input:text').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            });

        }
        if (this.value == "User Select") {
            $('input:text').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            });
        }
    })
});
```

here last condition is not working, please help

Comment: @user..your question is not at all clear.. explain more.

Comment: What have you tried?  What isn't working?  And what does this have to do with jQuery?  (Hint: These are set to `AutoPostBack="True"` which is going to reload the whole page, rendering any JavaScript event handlers moot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a common class to all dropdownlist and use class selector to bind the change event using jQuery

**HTML**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" class="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaritalStatus" class="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.ddl').change(function(){
     alert(this.id);
 });
```

If you do not want to use class selector, you will need to bind event with id selector

```
$('#<%= ddlGender.ClientID %>, #<%= ddlMaritalStatus.ClientID %>').change(function(){
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function and invoke it on onchange event of dropdownlist...

```
    DropDownList ID="ddlGender" class="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="Check()">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaritalStatus" class="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="Check()">

    function Check()
    {
       alert('Hii');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventHandler1">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaritalStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventHandler2">
```

In code-behind add below functions for each dropdownlist

```
void EventHandler1(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // code for event handler1
}


void EventHandler2(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // code for event handler1
}
```

For more details check example given in below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanx brother, but i would like it with jquery or javascript... Thanx :D